# Flutter save data as file in project folder

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Hi I am quite new to Flutter.
While running the app I take a screenshot of a widget, which I then would like look into. Therefore, I need to save this screenshot somewhere. Either on my local PC, e.g. in the project's assets or on the emulator. I tried following to save the image in the assets folder, without luck:

```
final RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = buttonKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
var rendering = await boundary.toImage();

var byteData = await rendering.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);
var pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();

File('./test_img.png').writeAsBytesSync(pngBytes);
```

Unfortunately this results in following error message: `[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = './test_img.png' (OS Error: Read-only file system, errno = 30)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if understand your question correctly, but the way I understood it is that you want to have some pictures in your project/app which are stored in the device not in the internet.

If thats what you meant then the answer to that is very easy, first you will have to create a new folder(in the project level) named "assets" and inside it a new folder called "images" after that you have to go to the pubspec.yamal file and enable the assets: like below

```
  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

Also you have to make sure that you have the indentations right 2 spaces otherwise it wont work.

After you enable it below you will have to add the path to the images folder as shown above again make sure you have the right indentations because otherwise it wont work.

The way you call those images and use them is pretty straightforward as shown below:

```
Center(
 child: Image.asset('assets/images/test_img.png',),
),
```

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I want the exact opposite. Save an image created on runtime under assets

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I read the updated question and I think [this](https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot) package will work great for your project.

Comment: Thanks for researching it. Unfortunately the screenshot use case was only an example. I would like to know how I can generally persistently save data to my local machine

Comment: What kind of data are we talking here, photos, files, numbers? or all the above and more?

Comment: As mentioned in my example, it is either an `Image` or a `List<bytes>`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're wanting to generate screenshots and save them somewhere on your local machine, e.g. in a folder in your project directory. You can do this using flutter's integration test framework.  Here are some helpful references:

https://medium.com/flutter-community/testing-flutter-ui-with-flutter-driver-c1583681e337

https://blog.codemagic.io/flutter-automated-screenshot-testing/

https://dev.to/mjablecnik/take-screenshot-during-flutter-integration-tests-435k

https://medium.com/@nocnoc/automated-screenshots-for-flutter-f78be70cd5fd

You can also directly take more complete display screenshots via the terminal command `flutter screenshot`, which captures the entire display, not just your app's UI.  You can execute this via Dart code in the context of an integration test's driver with:

```
import 'dart:io';

await Process.run('flutter', ['screenshot', '-o', 'image.jpg']);
```

A little more discussion about the pros and cons about doing it this way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70615760/5464788).